# itext7: Inconsistent Permission Flag in API

Tags: itext7

Before merging a list of files, I grab their assembly permission using `PdfReader`:

```
long PdfReader.getPermissions()
```

and check the result using `PdfEncryptor`:

```
static boolean PdfEncryptor.isAssemblyAllowed(int permissions)
```

As you see the first line of code returns a `long`, while the second expects an `int`. If I just cast the `long` to an `int`, the method `PdfEncryptor.isAssemblyAllowed` always returns true. But later in the code when I go to perform the actual merging, an error is thrown saying I lack the necessary permissions.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something in how the permission flag should be used?

As a workaround one can use the method

```
public boolean PdfReader.isOpenedWithFullPermission()
```

and don't merge if this returns false. But this might be over cautious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither iText 5 nor iText 7 checks the detail permissions when operating on PDFs. When they do check permissions for some operation, they only call `PdfReader.isOpenedWithFullPermission()`.

The reason for this may be that the individual permissions originally have been designed to match specific GUI operations in Adobe Acrobat which do not directly match specific API calls of iText.

Thus, if you regularly have to deal with documents with restricted permissions, consider setting the `UnethicalReading` flag, checking the appropriate flags in your code, and rejecting documents only according to that check.

---

As an aside, your current check is based on `isAssemblyAllowed`. The flag is specified as:

> Assemble the document (insert, rotate, or delete
> pages and create document outline items or thumbnail images), even if bit 4 [Modify the contents of the document] is clear.

Thus, this does not really match the permission you are looking for as it essentially refers to the *target* document (i.e. the merge result) while you test the source document. More appropriately, therefore, would be testing `isCopyAllowed`.

Comment: Intentions aside, the API is inconsistent. As for using the UnethicalReading flag, my sense of ethics forbids it. It's that same sense of ethics that makes me follow the projects's AGPL.

Comment: The name `UnethicalReading` indeed is not chosen wisely.